# powershell install multiple software packages, disable UAC

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

wondering if there is a way to make powershell not open UAC prompt and just run through an install script, for example

```
Get-Url http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/375.126/chrome_installer.exe c:\temp\chrome_installer.exe
Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\temp\chrome_installer.exe' -ArgumentList '/silent', '/install' -Wait
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\temp\DifferentProgram.exe' -ArgumentList '/argument' -Wait
```

Comment: If you open the PowerShell already elevated there will be no UAC prompt. If you don't have admin privileges you're out of luck. You cannot bypass UAC.

Comment: UAC prompt is a security measure that's in place, allowing scripts or programs to randomly disable it just to avoid the prompt defeats the purpose of having it. The only thing you can do it run the script from an elevated PowerShell session (Run As Administrator)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I work in the IT department at my company, so I have admin privs. If I run the script as administrator you are saying UAC prompts will not come up?